# Is there an SageMath function for printing out the steps performed of in e.g Calculus?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sage, calculus

#### Background

*Notice: I am a bit sleep deprived so, please point out any improvements I could make. It doesn't need to sound kind, thanks.*

Noted this now: The title maybe could read

*Is there a way in SageMath to show the 'simplified' steps it performs in Calculus?*

##### my question is pretty short

And I have searched Math.StackExchange, Stackoverflow, (..) and other resources (docs of SageMath, Google, and so on).
But I have not really found anything that is even close to my question.

### Context

Providing some context, I like to learn math. Especially because I can use SageMath to try to challenge myself, but I am quite slow (which is why I am trying it in SageMath as well)

In Calculus, I often find it confusing (some times) that, one equation is simplified in mostly the first steps (this is not the confusing part) the confusion I have is when I have "forgotten" a certain piece of math (which happens often, and as I am slow(slower than anyone else) I often end up just spending many hours on one simple basic thing.

I My question is related to the above, in the sense that I would like to be able to tell SageMath to simplify, and not simplify. (This might and probably do sound weird) But, that is my question, put simply.

as it's a small question I am a bit unsure how much I should try to explain, but if SageMath simplifies something, I would like to get a explanation to how it performed it. Instead of just letting me enter a input and it outputs the output but simplified.
This, **for me** becomes a problem because I need to see the exact "steps" (just because as said, I am quite slow at understanding basic things)

I will try to ask the same question but more shortly (to try to explain it the best I can)

I specifically want to just, get the steps that was performed by SageMath when it simplifies or "solves" (integral. or derivative.)

Thanks!
I have had this problem for awhile, but always kind of tried to find another way around it, and I am aware *this question likely is to be easy, probably obvious for many people, but for me it isn't*

I wish you a nice continuing day!
Will.

##### References

- https://wiki.sagemath.org/Differential_Calculus
- https://doc.sagemath.org

Comment: Please note; I cannot stress this enough: if I can improve it, point it out! and again this is , a problem I have (if some doesn't understand what problem I have it's - really just, How to tell sagemath to explain what it did instead of showing a complete simplified/solved output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update:

Still sleep deprived but I managed to get an answer.
the solution was found to be quite simple; it was a configuration I changed, in the config file;